# Why the sql is giving result even if the column doesn't exist in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql in SQLite3 where i just want to check if a column exists in a table or not?
For this i used the command Select and try Catch but whenever i am giving the columns name in numbers like 1,'2' "3" like this it return the columns with same numbers like 1,2 ,3 without showing errors why?

```
select 20 from Student;

20
20
20
20
20
20
```

shows 20 till number of rows exists in my actual Student table.

Comment: To check if a column actually exists, you would have to hit the information schema tables.  But, if you are checking for this from your application code, then already you are probably going wrong somewhere.  Your app should implicitly assume a certain database and table structure; it should not have to figure this out at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I learned that it's not a good thing to set column names with numerical value but if your column names are indeed in numerical values, you should add backticks\backquotes to your query. For example:

```
SELECT `20` FROM Student;
```

This way you'll get the following error if the column doesn't exist:

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column '20' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table` LIKE 'fieldname';
```

For MySQL this will return a column's information if the column exists where `table` is your table name and 'fieldname' is the column name. It will return nothing if the column does not exist